# Markers don't show on Google Maps v2

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm and Android newbie and I'm with some difficult getting a Google Maps v2 markers to display. If I put a single test marker, with some hardcoded values in it it works pretty well. However, my code doesn't seem to work.

I've already debuged and saw the values are correct and entering the function, but I can't get it to work.

I'm also debugging to a physical device.

Here's the code

```
private void inflateGoogleMap(ArrayList<Geocache> cacheList){
    GoogleMap map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager()

            .findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-33.867, 151.206);

        map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(sydney, 13));


        for(int i=0; i<cacheList.size(); i++){
            Log.d("CACHE_NAME", cacheList.get(i).getName()); 
            Log.d("CACHE_LAT", Double.toString(cacheList.get(i).getLatitude()));
            Log.d("CACHE_LONG",  Double.toString(cacheList.get(i).getLongitude()));

            Double cacheLat = cacheList.get(i).getLatitude();
            Double cacheLong = cacheList.get(i).getLongitude();
            LatLng pos = new LatLng(cacheLat, cacheLong);
            map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(pos));

                    //Log.d("CACHE_TYPE", json.getString("type"));
                    //Log.d("CACHE_REGION", json.getString("region"));
        /*Marker marker =   map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .title(cacheList.get(i).getName())
                .snippet(cacheList.get(i).getName())
                .position(new LatLng(cacheList.get(i).getLatitude(), cacheList.get(i).getLongitude())));*/

        }
}
```

How I get the Json list

```
public void getNearbyGeocaches(double lat, double lon,int limit){
    //String url = "http://test.opencaching.com/api/geocache?center=38.642%2c-94.754&limit=5&Authorization="+API_KEY;

    String url = "http://test.opencaching.com/api/geocache?center="+lat+"%2c"+lon+"&limit="+limit+"&Authorization="+super.getApiKey();

    super.get(url, null, new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {
        @Override

        public void onSuccess(JSONArray response) {
            // Pull out the first event on the public timeline
            JSONObject json = null;
            ArrayList<Geocache> geoList = new ArrayList<Geocache>();
            //Log.d("JSON_LENGTH",Integer.toString(timeline.length()));

            for(int i = 0; i<response.length(); i++)
            {
                try {
                    //Cast response para JSONObject
                    json = (JSONObject) response.get(i);

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                try {

                    Geocache cache = new Geocache();
                    //Log.d("CACHE_NAME", json.getString("name"));
                    //Log.d("CACHE_TYPE", json.getString("type"));
                    //Log.d("CACHE_REGION", json.getString("region"));

                    cache.setName(json.getString("name"));
                    cache.setDescription(json.getString("description"));
                    JSONObject location = json.getJSONObject("location");
                    cache.setLatitude(Double.parseDouble(location.getString("lon")));
                    cache.setLongitude(Double.parseDouble(location.getString("lat")));
                    //Log.d("CACHE_LAT", location.getString("latitude"));
                    //Log.d("CACHE_LONG", location.getString("longitude"));
                    //cache.setName(firstEvent.getString("name"));
                    geoList.add(cache);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }



                //
            }

            inflateGoogleMap(geoList);

            // Do something with the response

        }
    }); 


}
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: could you get your lat and long values from JSON?

Comment: Yes. They show up on the log correctly...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I noticed that I switched the Latitude and Longitude when creating the marker.

I was passing latitutde a 151º value, when the ranges are from -90º to 90º

Answer (score 0):

Add marker this way..

```
Mmap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(pos).title(ad).snippet(details).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(markericon)));
```

where pos is `LatLng(lat,lon)` and
`title` is the title that is to be displayed in the snippet and
`details` is the description that is to be shown on the snippet and
`markericon` is the marker icon that is to be displayed.

Comment: What's the difference between this code and mine? Could you explain? I don't see any noticeable difference...

Comment: you are not specifying any marker icon to be shown..I dont know whether its compulsory to give a marker icon.Have a look at that code please..@joao

Comment: thanks. I don't have a cable to deploy on device right now, but will test asap and feedback on it ;)

Comment: I found the solution. Check my answer, and thanks for the help!